# Can I retrieve the position of an offline player in SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft Vanilla SMP, having access to the server, can I somehow retrieve the position of an offline player?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Use [NBTedit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/6661-nbtedit/) or its successor, [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac).

Download and run it, choose <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Open</kbd>, go to your Minecraft server directory, find `players` directory, and then select the name of player you want, for example `Player.dat`.

You should see something like this:

[image: Player.dat in NBTedit]

You need to go to "Pos", and there you have it, coords of player you wanted.
Just double click any to edit it.