# My Minecraft Server is Kicking me on Join

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So long story short, someone on my server had a shulker box with items that had almost every enchantment, when they broke the shulker, it crashed the server gave the popup in the title. The shukler didn't seem to go into anyone's inventory, so I was unable to remove it through NBT tags. Is there a way to remove it through my console? It should just be a ground item. (1.14.2)

Here is the error I get when I get kicked: `Tried to read NBT that was too big; tried to allocate: 2097179bytes were max is allowed: 2077152`

My Logs:

`[04:50:31] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, destination] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [Player, 0123, @e, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[04:50:31] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[04:50:31] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[04:50:31] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [Player, 0123, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[04:50:31] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets, location] and [teleport, targets, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[04:50:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.14.2
[04:50:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[04:50:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[04:50:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[04:50:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[04:50:32] [Server thread/INFO]: Using default channel type 
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 2 path $[0]
    at zm.a(SourceFile:507) ~[server.jar:?]
    at zm.a(SourceFile:523) ~[server.jar:?]
    at xu.g(SourceFile:146) ~[server.jar:?]
    at uf.C(SourceFile:122) [server.jar:?]
    at uf.<init>(SourceFile:30) [server.jar:?]
    at ug.d(SourceFile:185) [server.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:605) [server.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 2 path $[0]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1559) ~[server.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1401) ~[server.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:593) ~[server.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:414) ~[server.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81) ~[server.jar:?]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61) ~[server.jar:?]
    at zm.a(SourceFile:505) ~[server.jar:?]
    ... 7 more
[04:50:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "world"
[04:50:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default, bukkit
[04:50:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Loaded 6 recipes
[04:50:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Loaded 811 advancements
[04:51:01] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for dimension minecraft:overworld
[04:51:04] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[04:51:04] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[04:51:04] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[04:51:04] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[04:51:04] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[04:51:04] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[04:51:04] [Server-Worker-1/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[04:51:05] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 35%
[04:51:05] [Server thread/INFO]: Time elapsed: 3950 ms
[04:51:05] [Server thread/INFO]: Done (32.640s)! For help, type "help"
[04:54:12] [User Authenticator #1/INFO]: UUID of player 5Flux is 5ff152ef-37e9-4333-ae83-a810f275bbef
[04:54:12] [Server thread/INFO]: 5Flux[/73.189.252.114:58735] logged in with entity id 411 at (1276.6541195569728, 99.0, 86.94608153358048)
[04:54:13] [Server thread/INFO]: 5Flux joined the game
[04:54:14] [Server thread/INFO]: 5Flux lost connection: Disconnected
[04:54:14] [Server thread/INFO]: 5Flux left the game
[04:54:30] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping the server
[04:54:30] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[04:54:30] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving players
[04:54:30] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
[04:54:30] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'world'/minecraft:the_end
[04:54:30] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (DIM1): All chunks are saved
[04:54:30] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'world'/minecraft:the_nether
[04:54:30] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (DIM-1): All chunks are saved
[04:54:30] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving chunks for level 'world'/minecraft:overworld
[04:54:31] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (world): All chunks are saved
[04:54:31] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (DIM1): All chunks are saved
[04:54:31] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (DIM-1): All chunks are saved
[04:54:31] [Server thread/INFO]: ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage (world): All chunks are saved`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, use this command:

`/kill @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:(colour)_shulker_box"}}]`

Comment: I got "No entity was found".

Comment: It's probably not in the spawn chunks, so it's only loaded if there's a player in the area. Try putting it into a repeating command block: `/setblock 0 0 0 repeating_command_block{auto:1,Command:"kill @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:\"minecraft:(colour)_shulker_box\"}}]"}` This assumes that 0 0 is in the spawn chunks, otherwise: `/forceload add 0 0`

Comment: @FabianRöling the shulker got destroyed in front of me, and I can't even go into the server without getting kicked so placing a command block is no hope.

Comment: Are you the server owner? You can enter commands in the server console, just like in chat.

Comment: Im getting "The postion is not loaded" when trying to enter the command block in the area

Comment: Do you know the coordinate where the shulker box located? If so, force load that chunk

Answer (score 1):

Refering to this old question [Can I retrieve the position of an offline player in SMP?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38636/233443)

Download a nbt viewer and check ur coordinate b4 going offline. Forceload the chunk and run the command

```
/setblock 0 0 0 repeating_command_block{auto:1,Command:"kill @e[type=item,nbt={Item:{id:\"minecraft:(colour)_shulker_box\"}}]"}
```