# How can I get coordinates of where I was at a specific point in time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built an amazing underground house but accidentally fell out of the world. How do I get my coordinates at a specific moment in time so I can get back to my house without scouring the entire world?

I need to know exactly where I was at a certain tick in Minecraft. How do I determine this?

Comment: Why do people downvote without leaving feedback?

Comment: Because "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". In this case, I think it is unclear. Can you expand on your question?

Comment: @Joachim - I tried to edit it...

Comment: The "no research effort" part applies: this question has been asked and answered before. Unless you slept in a bed in that house, it was the last place you slept, and the bed hasn't been destroyed or is obstructed, so you can kill yourself and wake up there (which isn't your case because you already fell out of the world and are still asking), then there is no deterministic way.  You have to go into spectator mode and fly around, open your world in third party software to get a map or to explore, etc.

Comment: VTC as an example of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: @Joachim - This is not a duplicate! My original spawn location is not set at my house, it is in some random forest! Therefore, that question does not encompass mine!

Comment: You're right, it's not a duplicate. How about [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38636/can-i-retrieve-the-position-of-an-offline-player-in-smp), though? (Not that I want this to be a duplicate, but I can't imagine it not being asked before..)

Comment: @Joachim - Still not even close! Also, if you don't think it's a dupe, why did you VTC it as a dupe?

Comment: Because I thought it was at that point. That's how it goes at times :)

Comment: @Joachim - Have you voted to reopen?

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath - I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went to the folder for my mod, then to the *logs* folder, and found the log for the console. The console actually says where I spawned, and it was inside my house.

So I went to `My Mod 1/run/logs` and found the appropriate one.

Problem solved!

Comment: Your use of "mod" here suggests you're actually using a mod for this. Is that the case?

Comment: You had your spawnset inside your house? Or did your previous spawn coordinates get printed there?

Comment: @Ben - Yes, that is the case.

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues - No I had just quitted and saved the game there so when I reopened, I was still there, though I technically did not "spawn," per se, there.

Answer (score 4):

It is almost certainly impossible. Recalling your position from a certain point on time would require the game to document ALL positions you were ever in. Even with a position cache, this would be hard to do on Mojang’s part. So, the final answer is it’s impossible.

Comment: For Java Edition, the stuff that is printed to the console is saved somewhere, right? Where is it saved?

Comment: I don't think so. The console would overflow

Comment: Actually, there is and I found it! So problem solved!!

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath It would be greatly apreciated if you posted it as an anwser. I have NO clue how you did it tho.

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues - I posted it!